Why am I getting (Timestamp not found) error while using Motoko query function in frontend?
I was making a web app on Difinity's Internet Computer using Motoko language but when I try to call a query function from my frontend I got the Uncaught runtime error saying - 'Timestamp not found in query response. This suggests a malformed or malicious response.'
My query functions are not working.
I wrote this query function:
    stable var currentValue: Float= 100;

    public query func checkBalance (): async Float {
          return currentValue;
    };


I call it from my index.js file like this:
    import { dbank} from "../../declarations/dbank";

    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {

        let currentValue = await dbank.checkBalance();
        document.getElementById("value").innerText = currentValue;
    });

And I got this error:
Timestamp Error

Because Angela is using in the video some older version, newer versions of the dependencies will not work. Here is the solution, and is working perfectly.

Uninstall current dep :

npm uninstall @dfinity/agent @dfinity/candid @dfinity/principal webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server  


Reinstall with working versions: 

npm i @dfinity/agent@0.15.2 @dfinity/candid@0.15.2 @dfinity/principal@0.15.2 webpack@5.63.0 webpack-cli@5.0.0 webpack-dev-server@4.4.0


We need to update dfx but for those who don’t want to update OR are following “Web development course” by Angela Yu there is a fix: -
But you have to do this process everytime after you run:-
dfx deploy
npm start

Steps: -

Open index.js from YourProjectName/src/declarations/YourProjectName

Replace this line
const agent = new HttpAgent({ …options?.agentOptions });


with this one
const agent = new HttpAgent({
...options?.agentOptions,
verifyQuerySignatures: false,
});


save

Open index.js from your-project-name/src/declarations/YourProjectName_assets

Replace this line
const agent = new HttpAgent({ …options?.agentOptions });”


with this one
const agent = new HttpAgent({
...options?.agentOptions,
verifyQuerySignatures: false,
});


save

Also go back to index.js from YourProjectName\src\dbank_assets\src and save



Directory paths for those using vs-code:
https://i.sstatic.net/4abKuphL.png

